# Check if a file exists, and if so create a new file with a higher number

Tags: java, file-io, file

I'm trying to output a set of points that my program creates, and I would like to be able to run it multiple times without having to manually move the files or rename them.
The files that I output would have a name like "cluster-1.txt" (could be changed if needed). So I need my program to find out if a cluster output file exists, find the file with the highest number and create a file with a higher number.

For example, if the program is running for the first time it would check, find no file and create "cluster-0.txt"; if the program is running for the second time, it would check and find "cluster-0.txt" and create "cluster-1.txt"; if the program is running for the nth time,  it would check and find the file with the highest n value and the create a file called "cluster-n+1.txt".

If possible it should ignore any missing files in the middle. So, if I have cluster-0.txt, cluster-10.txt, and cluster-11.txt it should create cluster-12.txt. This is not essential, though.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share code where you have a specific question?

Comment: This worked, I'll post the code I have somewhere and put the link here later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Read all files in directory. [class File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html)
2. Parse name of files and retrieve number. [class String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
3. Choose only the highest number. [class Integer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and [class Math](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)
4. If highest number exist create file-[highest number + 1].txt else cluster-1.txt

Comment: I'm currently testing this out. I'll report back in a bit and post my code.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is probaby to get all the filenames in your output directory using [File.list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29), then look for the ones that match your pattern, either with hand-coded logic or [Regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html). Having scanned the whole list, you'll know what's the largest existing number.